# Arrays passed to function having different signature

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0

I have defined two functions

```
    public static void M1(ICollection<Employee> l)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("ICOllection called");
    }
    public  static void M1(IList<Employee> l){
        Console.WriteLine("IList called");
    }
```

Why does the call always go to the second function when the array implements both ICollection and IList? How is the precedence decided ?.

```
Employee[] emp = new[] {new Employee(),new Employee()};
M1(emp);
```

I know I can type cast and call the other functions

```
M1((ICollection<Employee>)emp);
```

Comment: @Veverke: Arrays do implement both `IList` and `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

`IList<T>` is a more specific type than `ICollection<T>` (because it implements `ICollection<T>`), so overload resolution will prefer `IList<T>`.

Comment: Reference: [IList<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

IList implements ICollection, but ICollection does not implement IList, so the compiler sends the call to the least primitive match to the Type that is passed in (i.e. IList).